# How can I use Nike+ with roller skates?

Tags: ipod, health.app

Is it possible to use Nike+ with rollerblade skates? How?

Comment: You might be better with one of the GPS based training apps.

Comment: Actually the new Nike+ App is GPS based (Called Nike+ GPS) - so no problem if you got an iOS device with GPS: http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/nike-gps/id387771637?mt=8

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nike+ is a step counter, so it's measuring steps. With rollerblades you're not stepping usually.

You can try to calibrate your device with your moves of your rollerblades, but I don't think it will measure it correctly.